# Как при помощи php определить факт пересечения линий?

Tags: php

Есть подходящий класс [Intersections](https://www.interestprograms.ru/source-codes-tochka-peresecheniya-dvuh-pryamyh-na-ploskosti). Не понятно куда и в каком виде подставлять свои значения.

Кажется, что факт пересечения можно определить проще, т.е. если не искать саму точку пересечения.

Например было:

> a = - 1.19, b = - 1.90

стало

> a = - 1.25, b = - 0.94

в данном примере **b** ушла выше **a** и пересекла ее.

Как определить данное пересечение при помощи PHP?

Спасибо!

Comment: Видимо Вам надо https://ru.onlinemschool.com/math/library/analytic_geometry/lines_intersection/

Comment: Если прямые не параллельны, то они пересекаются. Так что достаточно проверить на параллельность